# Single Activity and Multiple Fragment with different toolbar layouts

Tags: android, toolbar, fullscreen, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an app with Single Activity multiple Fragments architecture in my app. The problem is, there is one listing fragment with normal Toolbar, from here user can click and go to Details screen. Now in Details screen, I want the Activity to become Fullscreen with CoordinatorLayout and Collapsing Toolbar with StatusBar area covered in layout as transparent. And when user goes back to Listing screen. The Activity should disable fullscreen and again get the StatusBar color.

The problem here is I am setting the activity as fullscreen using following code:

`window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`

And when the user goes back, I am disabling the Fullscreen by the following code:

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
```

After disabling the fullscreen, in my previous fragment, I am getting UI bounds clipped off.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your DetailsActivity -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: This will remove my status bar. I don't want that. I want overlapping status bar on my screen.

Comment: @mithil1501 then you should only use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using

`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`
for your activity.

and in your XML `activity` build in custom toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in your activity class

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

Now for your `fragments`, all you have to do is to show or hide this `toolbar` depends on the `fragment` you want to the same or another `toolbar` , And you can do that with `OnResume` and `OnPause` of the fragments.

Comment: But what about the status bar? How to switch between the fragments, with status bar area covered in one fragment while uncovered in other.

Comment: Inside of OnResume and OnPause of the activity you want to change the status bar you but your code there to hide it and give you full screen